# Trying to communicate with a REST service with NSIS

Tags: web-services, rest, curl, nsis

All I am trying to do is send an HTTP GET with Querystring or HTTP POST to a web service from within a custom page in an NSIS installer.

The problem is that most plugins can upload/download files, but not simply call a service and return the response. The recommend plugin to use is NsisUrlLib. I tried this, and while it works with simple GET requests, it fails and throws an error if you have querystring parameters in the URL, such as:

```
NsisUrlLib::UrlOpen /NOUNLOAD "http://tc.hwidev.com?var=value"
Pop $connectResult
```

NSISdl,INetC, and other plugins work with querystrings but can only be used to upload/download files.

I tried using the ExecDos plugin to call cURL.exe from the command line like so:

```
ExecDos::exec /TOSTACK "curl" "http://tc.hwidev.com"
Pop $connectResult
```

But I can't figure out how to get the data returned from the URL passed back to NSIS. The above code just returns an integer into $connectResult which probably represents the return code from CURL. How do I get the actual HTML returned from the URL onto the NSIS stack or into a variable?

Alternatively, can anyone recommend a better way to accomplish this? Calling a webservice seems so basic that thousands of people should have already figured this out.

Answer (score 2):

NSISdl, Inetc etc, aren't just for uploading/downloading files. I think you are misunderstanding this point. You can use them to call REST apis, but you'll need to save the answer to a local file, and then parse it.

Example: Calling to an REST api that answers XML:

```
# Call to REST API
NSISdl::download_quiet "http://remotesite?restparams" "$TEMP/result.xml"

# Parse answer
nsisXML::create
nsisXML::load "$TEMP/result.xml"
nsisXML::select "/response/status"

# Clean
delete "$TEMP/result.xml"
```

That's it.

Comment: Of course, I recommend you create macros to maintain your code clean.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSISdl::download_quiet "http://127.0.0.1/vid.php?vid=1" "$TEMP/checkvid.txt"   

FileOpen $0 $TEMP\checkvid.txt r

FileRead $0 $1

DetailPrint $1

FileClose $0

${If} $1 == "vidNTYE1203"

MessageBox MB_OK "video found"

Delete "$TEMP\checkvid.txt"         

${Else} 

MessageBox MB_OK  "bye bye"

Delete "$TEMP\checkvid.txt"

Quit 

${EndIf}
```

This is my work snippet for production.Working good,for me.Pay attention for 'Delete' command and '\' slash .

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend [INetC](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Inetc_plug-in) over NsisUrlLib, the older firefox installer used it with much success.